# Shouldn't a VSYNC'ed cycle in a game take a constant amount of time?

Tags: c, windows, sdl, game-physics

I am writing a little snake game in C, using SDL, on Windows.
On each frame I move each square a constant amount of pixels (e.g. 2 pixels).

As long as I have Vsync enabled, the movement is very smooth. However, I was trying to achieve the same smoothness without Vsync, just to learn how things work, and after a lot of struggle I have managed to time the cycles down to almost a perfect 0.016667 seconds (60Hz monitor here) by using the Performance Counter to measure repeated SDL_Delay(1) until 0.014 seconds of a cycle + an empty loop up to 0.016667s. This works great (so it's not a matter of SDL_Delay(1) taking more than it should) I guess, because 1 in 1000 frames is off by 0.1ms, and this should not be noticeable.

But the movement is still jerky sometimes - as if it doesn't move at all for one frame and then catches up double on the next. This I think boils down to the fact that the game is updating and rendering when it should, but the actual display on the monitor takes place a little sooner than it should, and then a little later than it should.

So I did some time measurements and the results are very surprising to me - see attached graphs. With Vsync enabled, the measured cycle times are all over the place - much much worse than the non-vsynced version - and I was expecting a perfect constant time. **So the question is: Is the actual time between 2 consecutive drawings to the physical monitor not constant?** Because if that is the case there is no way you can achieve what I am trying without some sort of feedback of when exactly the last drawing took place...

P.S. The update and rendering are very very fast - e.g. if the cycle is not limited it can go millions of times per second. So that is not slowing the cycle down.

[image]

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

#define NONE 0
#define QUIT 1
#define LEFT 2
#define RIGHT 3
#define UP 4
#define DOWN 5

typedef struct Color
{
    char R, G, B, A;
}Color;

typedef struct Square
{
    int x, y, side, dir;
    Color color;
}Square;


const int WINDOW_W = 600;
const int WINDOW_H = 800;
const int SQ_SIDE = 48;
const Color SQ_COLOR = {0, 0, 0x99, 0xFF};
const Color BG_COLOR = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

SDL_Window* g_window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* g_renderer = NULL;

float speed = 120; /* pixels per second */
int display_refresh_rate;

bool vsync_enabled = false; /* enable/disable vsync from here */

bool clear_screen(void);
void draw_rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color);
void update_square_position(Square *square);
int process_input_events();


int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    g_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    int renderer_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    if(vsync_enabled) renderer_flags |= SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;

    g_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(g_window, -1, renderer_flags);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(g_renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    int display_index;
    SDL_DisplayMode display_mode;
    display_index = SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex(g_window);
    SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(display_index, &display_mode);

    display_refresh_rate = display_mode.refresh_rate;
    float target_cycle_time = 1.0f / display_refresh_rate;

    clear_screen();

    unsigned long long tick_now = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    unsigned long long last_render_tick = tick_now;

    float time_from_last_render = 0.0f;
    float render_times_array[3601];

    float perf_freq = (float)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();
    timeBeginPeriod(1);

    Square *square = (Square*) malloc(sizeof(Square));

    square->x = 50;
    square->y = 50;
    square->color = SQ_COLOR;
    square->side = SQ_SIDE;
    square->dir = RIGHT;

    int i = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        tick_now = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
        time_from_last_render = (tick_now - last_render_tick) / perf_freq;

        if(time_from_last_render < target_cycle_time - 0.002f)
            SDL_Delay(1);


        if(vsync_enabled || (time_from_last_render >= target_cycle_time))
        {
            if(process_input_events()== QUIT) break;

            update_square_position(square);

            clear_screen();
            draw_rect(square->x, square->y, SQ_SIDE, SQ_SIDE, square->color);
            SDL_RenderPresent(g_renderer);

            last_render_tick = tick_now;

            /* save 3600 timestamps and print them */
            render_times_array[i++] = time_from_last_render;
            if(i >= 3600)
            {
                clear_screen();
                int j;
                for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    printf("%f\n", render_times_array[j]);

                i=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(g_window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(g_renderer);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

bool clear_screen(void)
{
    /* SDL functions return 0 on success! */
    if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_renderer, BG_COLOR.R, BG_COLOR.G, BG_COLOR.B, BG_COLOR.A))
        return false;
    else if(SDL_RenderClear(g_renderer))
        return false;

    return true;
}

void draw_rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color)
{
    SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, width, height};
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_renderer, color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(g_renderer, &rect);
}

void update_square_position(Square *square)
{
    int step = speed / display_refresh_rate;

    if(square->dir == RIGHT)
    {
        square->x += step;
        if(square->x > WINDOW_W - 100) square->dir = DOWN;
    }

    if(square->dir == LEFT)
    {
        square->x -= step;
        if(square->x < 50) square->dir = UP;
    }

    if(square->dir == DOWN)
    {
        square->y += step;
        if(square->y > WINDOW_H - 100) square->dir = LEFT;
    }

    if(square->dir == UP)
    {
        square->y -= step;
        if(square->y < 50) square->dir = RIGHT;
    }
}

int process_input_events()
{
    SDL_Event event_handler;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event_handler) != 0)
    {
        if(event_handler.type == SDL_QUIT)
            return QUIT;
    }
    return NONE;
}
```

Comment: OK, I will try to simplify the thing as much as I can and post it. The graphs are right,  the one on top is without vsync, the cycle times are always >= 1/60 (because probably once in a while, the last SDL_Delay(1) takes more than 2 or 3 ms and makes the cycle last longer. You can see that none of the cycles are shorter than 1/60. What puzzles me is the one below, with vsync, because I thought the cycles will be synch'ed to the refresh rate, and that the period between 2 refreshes is constant. But here the average period will match my refresh rate (60.07 Hz), but the period is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

For the question: **Is the actual time between 2 consecutive drawings to the physical monitor not constant?** the answer is **NO** because it will depend on what it needs to be render.

You are saying that you move your squares on each frame and thats an error because as you see, the frames aren't displayed in constant time. You need to code this behavior (and all your game logic) in a framerate independent manner, instead of moving *N* pixels each frame, you need to set a speed based in time, could it be *2pixels each 3ms* and then each frame you should compute the elapsed time between frames (google that for SDL) and with that elapsed time you could move your objects. Eg (in pseudo code).

```
float speed = 10;
float timeFrameInMS = 2;

onNewFrame(){
    float elapsedTimeInMS = ...getting the elapsed time.. // lets say it is .5ms
    float movePercentage = elapsedTimeInMS/timeFrameInMS // .25
    float distanceToMove = speed*movePercentage.
    /*Move objects*/
}
```

You need to start thinking in time instead of frames, because the device running the game could at some moment have a "freeze" and the time between frames could be 1 second for example (it happens). It could also be the other way, there could be a device running at twice the framerate you are developing, if you base your logic on frames then this device will have everything at double the speed.

Here is a book on the topic and with other basic tecniques for game development: [Game Programming Algorithms and Techniques: A Platform-Agnostic Approach](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zfMSjGrMkovMjJg9JJOT8xNVSgoyk8vSszNzcxLV0jMSc8vyizJyC0GADHKDxU&q=game+programming+algorithms&oq=game+programming+algoritm&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j46i13j0i13j0i5i13i30.6250j0j7&client=ms-android-americamovil-mx-revc&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Well I have read all about the time-based approach and tried that first, but it doesn't work for me because the movement I need @ 120 pixels per second speed is exactly 2 pixels per frame. So if the timing is a little under, for example if the calculation is that I should move 1.9997 pixels, I have to round that down. Or if I round it up, where is the limit? Like should 1.6 pixels be a 1 or a 2? So in this case, moving 2D squares at a speed of 120, 180, 240 pixels per second, it should always be a round number of pixels because otherwise it gets very jerky... in my experience..

Comment: Also in the game I read the refresh rate of the monitor and adapt the speed as possible - like if it's closer to 60 fps, I go with 2 px/frame, if it's closer to 120 fps, I go with 1 px/frame, etc. I understand how a time based, pixel-fraction approach works in 3d games but I don't understand how it should work on 2D games with relatively slow speeds..

Comment: The independent framerate approach works just the same for 2D than for 3D. You can't trust the reported refresh rate of the monitor because that is not the refresh rate of the computer (and for your game) each cycle/frame depends on the CPU and GPU, if your code is taking long to be resolved lets say 1second, during that second your monitor could have probably 60-120 screen refresh, but for your game only one. You can't develop thinking on the refresh rate of the monitor, you have to develop thinking in terms of time because if the computer gets slow at some moment the the framerate changes

Comment: For the partial pixels. I'm assuming you are using the normal transformation matrix approach and if you make a translation (a movement around x,y,z axis) you can use floating values and let the GPU worries for that partial position at the end, because that 1.6 position could in some scenarios render two pixels but one of them with transparency (kind of a neighboring effect) and the units used in the coordinate space are not pixels, because the coordinate space could have a different size than the viewport/screen or could be scaled.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will look more into what you are saying, I was placing the squares at a computed, rounded to integer coordinate. And even if I kept track of the "fractions" and added them up in time until they make a full pixel, the movement was bad.

Comment: No problem. I'll leave the title of a book that is basic for game development and explains this (framerate independent development) and some other tactics for game development, it is called: `Game Programming Algorithms and Techniques: A Platform-Agnostic Approach`